# Can we profile and log a distributed program in elexir?

Tags: elixir, profiling, distributed-system

I want to implement a map-reduce distributed system with elixir (as a project for one of my courses) but before I begin I need to find some tools.

For my project, I need to profile the system's behaviour and performance. For instance I want to the check how performance changes with increasing the problem size, or changing the number of workers etc., or what happens if we have link/process failures. Since the program is distributed I have no idea how to achieve such profiling. I couldn't find any library for my use case, but since I'm new to the language maybe there are ways I do not know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "distributed tracing" and there is few projects that support that. For example [OpenTelemetry](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-erlang). Additionally you want to gather metrics for your application. There is few approaches to that, and currently the community is gathered around [`telemetry`](https://github.com/beam-telemetry/telemetry). More informations about current state of observability in Erlang is available in list prepared by [Erlang Ecosystem Foundation Observability WG](https://github.com/erlef/eef-observability-wg).